# Combining Union results with duplicate lines

Tags: sql-server, union

I have the below SQL Query:

```
SELECT qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_Name, qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID, tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear, tblFMS_Data.FM_Period,
 tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_ID, Sum(IIf([FM_TrustNo]=0 And [FM_Incident]=25 And [Ref_Fault_Valid_Combo]=-1,1,0)) AS Success,
 Sum(IIf([FM_Incident]=25 And [Ref_Fault_Valid_Combo]=-1,1,0)) AS CountPrevent
FROM 
(
 ( 
  ( tblFMS_Data INNER JOIN qryRef_Routes_tbl ON tblFMS_Data.FM_Route = qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID )
    INNER JOIN tblRCM_II_Assets ON tblFMS_Data.FM_EllipseNo = tblRCM_II_Assets.RI_Number 
  )
  INNER JOIN tblPeriod_Lookup ON tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear = tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_FinYear
   AND tblFMS_Data.FM_Period = tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_PeriodNo
)
INNER JOIN qryRef_Detectable_Failure_Valid_Combo ON tblFMS_Data.FM_Component2 = qryRef_Detectable_Failure_Valid_Combo.Ref_Fault_Comp2_ID
 AND tblFMS_Data.FM_Component = qryRef_Detectable_Failure_Valid_Combo.Ref_Fault_Comp1_ID
GROUP BY qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_Name, qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID, tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear, tblFMS_Data.FM_Period, tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_ID
HAVING
(
 (
  tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_ID Between [Forms]![frmMainMenu]![PriorPeriodID] And
  ([Forms]![frmMainMenu]![PriorPeriodID]-12)
  )
)
UNION
SELECT qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_Name, qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID, tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear, tblFMS_Data.FM_Period,
 tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_ID, Sum(IIf([FM_TrustNo]=0 And [FM_Incident]=25 And [Ref_Fault_Valid_Combo]=-1,1,0)) AS Success,
 Sum(IIf([FM_Incident]=25 And [Ref_Fault_Valid_Combo]=-1,1,0)) AS CountPrevent
FROM
(
 (
  ( tblFMS_Data INNER JOIN qryRef_Routes_tbl ON tblFMS_Data.FM_Route = qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID)
    INNER JOIN tblRCM_II_Assets ON tblFMS_Data.FM_EllipseNo = tblRCM_II_Assets.RI_Pway_Number
  )
  INNER JOIN tblPeriod_Lookup ON tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear = tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_FinYear
   AND tblFMS_Data.FM_Period = tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_PeriodNo
)
INNER JOIN qryRef_Detectable_Failure_Valid_Combo ON tblFMS_Data.FM_Component2 = qryRef_Detectable_Failure_Valid_Combo.Ref_Fault_Comp2_ID
 AND tblFMS_Data.FM_Component = qryRef_Detectable_Failure_Valid_Combo.Ref_Fault_Comp1_ID
GROUP BY qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_Name, qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID, tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear, tblFMS_Data.FM_Period, tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_ID
HAVING
(
 (
   tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_ID Between [Forms]![frmMainMenu]![PriorPeriodID] And [Forms]![frmMainMenu]![PriorPeriodID]-12
  )
);
```

The results from this are duplicated.  I want the results of the duplicated lines to be combined.

Note the Join queries are slightly different in the 2 queries being Union'd

Comment: Do you mean using "first" of each group?

Comment: Please format your sql query in a better way.

Comment: `Union` executes a distinct on the combined dataset.  `Union all` will keep all records from both sets thus allowing duplicates.  So if you're seeing TRUE duplicate records using union, either the engine is broke/buggy or your record isn't really identical (perhaps non-display characters?)  to "Combine" the reocrds you would need to encase the union in an outer select which aggregrates(sums, counts) and groups by the appropriate fields.

Comment: I don't think that this is MySQL.

Comment: sorry im new to this, it is microsoft access i am working with and I can mod my tags :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION DISTINCT` if you do not want duplicated values

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean combine the results of the unions on the aggregates...

```
SELECT sub.Ref_Route_Name
     , sub.Ref_Route_ID
     , sub.FM_FinYear
     , sub.FM_Period
     , sub.PL_ID
     , Sum(sub.Success) as Success
     , Sum(sub.CountPrevent) as countPrevent
FROM (
SELECT qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_Name
     , qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID
     , tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear
     , tblFMS_Data.FM_Period
     , tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_ID
     , Sum(IIf([FM_TrustNo]=0 And [FM_Incident]=25 And [Ref_Fault_Valid_Combo]=-1,1,0)) AS Success
     , Sum(IIf([FM_Incident]=25 And [Ref_Fault_Valid_Combo]=-1,1,0)) AS CountPrevent
FROM tblFMS_Data 
INNER JOIN qryRef_Routes_tbl 
  ON tblFMS_Data.FM_Route = qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID 
INNER JOIN tblRCM_II_Assets 
  ON tblFMS_Data.FM_EllipseNo = tblRCM_II_Assets.RI_Number 
INNER JOIN tblPeriod_Lookup PL
  ON tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear = tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_FinYear
 AND tblFMS_Data.FM_Period = tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_PeriodNo
INNER JOIN qryRef_Detectable_Failure_Valid_Combo  rdfvc
  ON tblFMS_Data.FM_Component2 = rdfvc.Ref_Fault_Comp2_ID
 AND tblFMS_Data.FM_Component = rdfvc.Ref_Fault_Comp1_ID
WHERE PL.PL_ID Between [Forms]![frmMainMenu]![PriorPeriodID] And[Forms]![frmMainMenu]![PriorPeriodID]-12
GROUP BY qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_Name
    , qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID
    , tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear
    , tblFMS_Data.FM_Period, tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_Name
     , qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID
     , tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear
     , tblFMS_Data.FM_Period
     , tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_ID
     , Sum(IIf([FM_TrustNo]=0 And [FM_Incident]=25 And [Ref_Fault_Valid_Combo]=-1,1,0)) AS Success
     , Sum(IIf([FM_Incident]=25 And [Ref_Fault_Valid_Combo]=-1,1,0)) AS CountPrevent
FROM tblFMS_Data 
INNER JOIN qryRef_Routes_tbl 
  ON tblFMS_Data.FM_Route = qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID
INNER JOIN tblRCM_II_Assets 
  ON tblFMS_Data.FM_EllipseNo = tblRCM_II_Assets.RI_Pway_Number
INNER JOIN tblPeriod_Lookup PL 
  ON tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear = tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_FinYear
 AND tblFMS_Data.FM_Period = tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_PeriodNo
INNER JOIN qryRef_Detectable_Failure_Valid_Combo rdfvc
  ON tblFMS_Data.FM_Component2 = rdfvc.Ref_Fault_Comp2_ID
 AND tblFMS_Data.FM_Component = rdfvc.Ref_Fault_Comp1_ID
WHERE  PL.PL_ID Between [Forms]![frmMainMenu]![PriorPeriodID] And [Forms]![frmMainMenu]![PriorPeriodID]-12
GROUP BY qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_Name
       , qryRef_Routes_tbl.Ref_Route_ID
       , tblFMS_Data.FM_FinYear
       , tblFMS_Data.FM_Period
       , tblPeriod_Lookup.PL_ID

) Sub
GROUP BY Sub.Ref_Route_Name
       , sub.Ref_Route_ID
       , sub.FM_FinYear
       , sub.FM_Period
       , sub.PL_ID
```

Not sure if duplicates results from queries should be "Combined" or eliminated as duplicate so added a union all.

Comment: Nope doesnt work -  says 'Characters found after end of SQL statement

Comment: Ah a  ) before the union all needs/needed to be removed.

Comment: sorry this was written in Microsoft Access which is the program I am using